# Sizing Views for SwiftUI (iPod Touch 7th Gen)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm looking for a solution to make the SwiftUI views to be the same relative size for all sizes of iOS devices.  I can't find anything with elegant solutions to this.

With UIKit, you can just use constraints with relation to the size of other views, and with SwiftUI I know you can use GeometryReader, but am I supposed to place every single view inside GeometryReader?

It seems like there should be a more elegant solution to this but I haven't found one in any tutorials or articles I've read, everyone just seems to use static size parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use the GeometryReader with constants as multipliers.